# maven-publish repository credentials depend on custom task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, maven-publish

I have a custom task to get credentials from a server:

```
task getToken {
    ext.token = // curl whatever
}
```

I would like to use the output of this task in the credentials block in the publications repositories, something like this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "https://somewhere.com/repo"

            credentials {
                username System.properties['user.name']
                password getToken.token
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't know when the credentials there are resolved, and obviously the task `getToken` would need to have completed before-hand.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable with the plugin here: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/pl.unity.lazy-credentials

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.pl.unity.gradle:lazy-credentials:1.2.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "pl.unity.lazy-credentials"

publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://somewhere.com/repo"
            lazyCredentials {
                username System.properties['user.name']
                password {
                    // some code here to request the token
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```